# Groovy gdk namespace collision

Tags: java, groovy, java-stream

Groovy is throwing a odd error when I use the `collect` method on the java 8 `Stream`s. This is my code:

```
someStream.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And this is the error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.LongPipeline$8.collect() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl) values: [java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@e41621]
Possible solutions: collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure), collect(java.util.function.Supplier, java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer, java.util.function.BiConsumer), close(), count()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.stream.LongPipeline$8.collect() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl) values: [java.util.stream.Collectors$CollectorImpl@e41621]
Possible solutions: collect(), collect(groovy.lang.Closure), collect(java.util.Collection, groovy.lang.Closure), collect(java.util.function.Supplier, java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer, java.util.function.BiConsumer), close(), count()
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Java 8 are you using I can't see `LongPipeline` in [the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-frame.html)?

The only reference to `LongPipeline` I can find, only has the following collect method:

```
collect(Supplier<R> resultFactory,
        ObjLongConsumer<R> accumulator,
        BiConsumer<R, R> combiner)
```

Which you can see in the exception you are being shown:

```
collect(java.util.function.Supplier, java.util.function.ObjLongConsumer, java.util.function.BiConsumer)
```

So even in Java, you wouldn't be able to call

```
someStream.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Huh.. Well that explains it. Now how the heck do I get this to work.... Thanks for the answer!